# Bootstrap v3 ROW of "href buttons" works in JSFiddle but creates a STACK of buttons on my webpage

Tags: html, button, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using bootstrap v3 the goal is to create a row of fixed width href buttons for navigation. The code, using nothing but bootstrap styled HTML, achieves this in JSFiddle using

```
.nav_btn
{
    width: 82px !important;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

<div class="col-md-10">
    <div class="btn-toolbar">
        <div class="btn-group">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default nav_btn" disabled>
            <span><strong>Portfolio</strong></span>         
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary nav_btn">
            <span><strong>Quote</strong></span>         
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-success nav_btn">
            <span><strong>BUY</strong></span>           
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-success nav_btn">
            <span><strong>SELL</strong></span>          
            </a>
           <a href="#" class="btn btn-info nav_btn">
            <span><strong>History</strong></span>           
           </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SBSgN/12/

The exact code shown, with custom .nav_btn styling as shown, displays the buttons... stacked vertically :( when inserted into HTML for an actual web page. The code is inside a container. No other div specifying a grid size (e.g. col-md-10) appears before the code in question.

What am I missing.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you provided, so it must be related to some code you didn't provide.

Comment: I accept Sean Ryan's answer because something else in the code could have prevented the desired result.

Comment: Solved! After much searching plus trial and error, I came up with a solution as seen here... http://jsfiddle.net/SBSgN/13/